# Are git annotated tags modifyable? If so, how?

Tags: git, git-tag

Modifying lightweight tags in git is working as intended. 
`git tag -f <tagname> <commit-id>`

But using the same with annotated tags seems to be causing trouble -

```
$ git cat-file -t tag2rag
tag
```

and

```
$ git cat-file -p tag2rag
object a7b4b4823f0222b79376e4c16bdbba0f3d1f5d33
type commit
tag tag2rag
tagger samshers <email@gmail.com> 1568930032 +00:00

tag to rag
```

then,

```
$ git tag -f tag2rag 3096b
Updated tag 'tag2rag' (was 8931274)
```

then,  **the unexpected**

```
$ git cat-file -t tag2rag
commit
```

and

```
$ git cat-file -p tag2rag
tree b0053bf300da86e5aeabafb29d7dedcdbf713d51
parent 49c74fafd7c69e938052a4cba96ad62999438413
author samshers <email@gmail.com> 1568910804 +0000
committer samshers <email@gmail.com> 1568910804 +0000

wowfiles in
```

Disclaimer: Well, I acknowledge that changing tags after publishing is not a good practice and could cause more collaboration issues. And instead a new tag should be created and published.
Well the purpose here is to understand git and how to do things in git.

Any suggestions on how to edit annotated tags.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no.

The longer answer is that they are exactly as modifiable as commits: not at all, but if you try hard enough, you can get a new and different commit—or annotated tag, in this case—and you can *trick* people into *thinking* you changed some existing object.

An annotated tag is composed of a lightweight tag—a reference that begins with `refs/tags/`—that points to an internal Git object of type tag:

```
$ git cat-file -t v2.4.0
tag
```

The underlying object has a hash ID:

```
$ git rev-parse v2.4.0
67308bd628c6235dbc1bad60c9ad1f2d27d576cc
```

This hash ID is the Git-style checksum of the object (header + contents):

```
$ git cat-file -p v2.4.0 | sed 's/@/ /'
object 3d4a3ffe64162b45ae7c991fc60623ecb4678cfd
type commit
tag v2.4.0
tagger Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com> 1430418320 -0700

Git 2.4
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
[snip]
```

You can make a new tag object with different contents (using `git tag` or `git mktag`, for instance) but if the contents differ, so will the hash ID.  You can then make the lightweight tag name point to the new tag object, using `git update-ref` for instance.

This does not modify the existing object in any way.  A naïve user, however, would now examine the tag uncritically, not notice that the `refs/tags/v2.4.0` name produces a new and different tag object ID, read the new and different tag object, and *think* the tag has changed.  (If the identifier inside the tag object still has the `v2.4.0` name, everything is in sync and perhaps the tag really has changed, from some points of view!)

Attempts to send this new updated tag to other Git repositories may succeed or fail, depending on their policy on replacing an existing tag-namespace ref and whether they had a copy of the previous tag <name,object> pair.

Comment: tx again. But what if i delete the tag and recreate it. Is that safe.

Comment: Deleting and re-creating the tag has the same effect: there's a new object (the annotated tag object) with a new hash ID, and a ref that holds the new hash ID. The old object remains until GCed. Any other Git that has the old object under the tag name may stick with the old one, or switch to the new one, depending on that other Git's policy.

Comment: Note that you can often tell some other Git that won't update a tag to *delete* its copy of the tag, then tell it to create a new tag with the same name. That works by default, so most servers obey this rule. It requires a separate "send push with delete request to server" step. You can do that regardless of how you go about replacing the tag in your own Git.